# How to change the android database storage path?

Tags: android

How do I change the android database storage path? The default path for database storage is / data / data / databases,I want to save it to sdcard, how to do?

Answer (score 8):

This is and old question, but answering may help others.

The easiest way to do this (only for debuggin environments) is to modify the constructor of the class:

```
public class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "/mnt/sdcard/database_name.db", null, 0);
    }
}
```

Remember to change for production environments with these lines:

```
public class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "database_name.db", null, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

SQLite's `openDatabase()` lets you provide a location for your database.

You should use [Context.getExternalFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir%28java.lang.String%29) to find the SD card's path instead of hardcoding it, though.  That link has some nice code samples which you should make use of.

Answer (score 2):

You can put and open the database from wherever you like, i.e.

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/sdcard/mydatabase.db", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```