# how change the place where the db file stores

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the android database storage path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911123/how-to-change-the-android-database-storage-path)

If my application is named,hello,so the db file will be stored in the `/data/hello/data/database`.
Right now,i want to change the place where the file is to be stored in.
Sould i change the source of android os?or any other idea?

Comment: You need to try to copy your database from assets folder to the place where you want to place it.

Answer (score 0):

Create the Database in the required path as below:

```
 File db = new File(DB_PATH, DB_NAME);
```

where

```
  DB_PATH =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()//if you want to create a database in SD Card
  DB_NAME = "hello.db";
```

Comment: @kaiwii ho found the solution?