# How change the path of save DataBase with ActionAndroid _ Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am using [ActionAndroid](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid) in my project.

How I can change the path of save `dataBase` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```
<manifest ...>
        <application android:name="com.activeandroid.app.Application" ...>

            ...

            <meta-data android:name="AA_DB_NAME" android:value="/mnt/sdcard/Pickrand.db" />
            <meta-data android:name="AA_DB_VERSION" android:value="5" />

        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks for @sasikumar ! I just c/p.

Answer (score 0):

```
File backupDB = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "Database.db");
File currentDB = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
if (currentDB.exists()) {
FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
src.close();
dst.close();
}
```

Also you need permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: In manifest I insert :<meta-data android:name="AA_DB_NAME" android:value="Pickrand.db" /> and <meta-data android:name="AA_DB_VERSION" android:value="5" /> for create database, I should delete them ?  and in your code where i should insert path ? for example this path : Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/" + MY_PACKAGE_NAME + MY_FolderName + DBNAME ;

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911123/how-to-change-the-android-database-storage-path

Comment: I am using ActionAndroid !